# How to add a modified extension to .NET framework?

Tags: .net, bdd, specflow

I have modified the code of Specflow, an open source tool for behavior driven development (BDD). Conventionally, this tool, like any other extensions, can be added through the menu Tools->Extension and updates to .NET. However, I need to find another way for integrating this modified tool to .NET framework. Can you please inform me how I can add a modified extension (in this case the modified Specflow) to .NET framework? Thanks in advance for your replies!
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: What did you change in SpecFlow? The Visual Studio Extension or the NuGet package?

Comment: I added a new feature to the source code of Specflow and recompiled it.